# Retrofit2.0 is returning 404 not found

Tags: android, retrofit

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl("http://ipAdress/SaveImg/DouBanGirl")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    imgApi imgService = retrofit.create(imgApi.class);
    Call<Img> imgCall = imgService.getImg("20151119");

    imgCall.enqueue(new Callback<Img>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<Img> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.code() + " ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());

        }
    });

}

public interface imgApi {
    @GET("/DouBanGirl")
    Call<Img> getImg(@Query("date") String date);
}
```

when i tried this, it is showing 404 not found. the url is correct, i checked that. 
I dont know what going on.

Comment: Have you included the port in base url?

Comment: If you get a 404 the URL does not exist at the server. Which URL do you want to connect to?

Comment: You have DouBanGirl both in base url and in GET path. I doubt, that it's correct :) Use baseUrl("http://ipAdress/SaveImg/DouBanGirl") and GET("/") or baseUrl("http://ipAdress/SaveImg") and @GET("/DouBanGirl")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to how Retrofit 2.0 uses Http Resolve for resolving the uri scheme of your endpoints, if you specify the baseurl like this `http://hello.com` and the endpoint URL as `/world/foo` it will break.

You need to use base URL `http://hello.com/` and endpoint URL `world/foo`.

The `/` makes the difference.

Comment: I have edited it as baseUrl  `http://ipAdress/SaveImg/DouBanGirl/ ` And `@GET("DouBanGirl")`, BUT it doesn't work , 404 again

Comment: @HugoXie Leave the base URL as `.baseUrl("http://ipAdress/")` and path at interface as `@GET("DouBanGirl")`

Answer (score 0):

The question were asked a while ago, but I answer this just in case anyone reached here in the future.
The Retrofit does not recognize `200` status code the way web browser or Postman does. It only detects `200` if only you send it bundled with an empty json, otherwise it acts like the server gave it `404` status code.
For example in Express js the code `res.sendStatus(200);` is not making Retrofit considers the task done and you should use something like `res.status(200).send({});`